# How to prove the independence of a variable that is the sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability

I have two independent random variables $X_{1}$ and $Y_{1}$. Both of them take two values: 1 and -1 with probability 1/2. 
I have the variable $Z$  that takes value 1 if $X_{1} + Y_{1} = 0 $ and -1 if $X_{1} + Y_{1} = \pm 2$.
So, P(Z=1) = P(Z=-1) = 1/2.

[In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32871/154124) is the proof that $Z$ is not independent of the pair $(X_{1}, Y_{1})$ but on pages 139 and 140 of "Counterexamples in Probability and Statistics" by By Joseph P. Romano, A.F. Siegel, the author says that $Z$ is independent of $X_{1}$ and $Y_{1}$ separately.

Authos doesn't prove this affirmation. I think the independence of $Z$ from only $X_{1}$ is demostrated fixing $Y_{1}$ to a value (like $Y_1 = 1$) and calculating:
$$P(Z = 1) = \sum_j P(X = -1) = 1/2$$

Am I right?

Comment: You said "$Z$ takes the value 1 if $X_1+Y_1=0$ and -1 if $X_1+Y_1=0$. There seems to be a mistake here...

Comment: Your link `In this question` has _nothing_ to do with the question asked here.

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard example (sometimes attributed to Bernstein)
in probability theory that if $X, Y, Z$ are Bernoulli random
variables with parameter $\frac 12$ with the property that
$(X,Y,Z)$ takes on values $(0,0,0), (0, 1, 1), (1,0,1), (1,1,0)$
with equal probability $\frac 14$, then $X,Y,Z$ are
*pairwise* independent random variables but *not mutually
independent* random variables. When you get your question properly
set up, see if setting $X_1 = (-1)^X, Y_1 = (-1)^Y, Z_1 = (-1)^Z$
helps.