# Question about independency of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, independence

let X, Y, Z be 3 random variables.

if X and Y are independent and  X and Z are independent,

is X and (Y,Z) also independent?

(if $$P(X \in A, Y \in B) =P(X \in A)P(Y\in B)$$ and
$$P(X \in A, Z \in B) =P(X \in A)P(Z\in B)$$

is $$P(X \in A, (Y,Z) \in B) =P(X \in A)P((Y,Z) \in B)$$ )?

Comment: Do you know what the tag (statistics) stands for? At present you are misusing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1570323/15941) for a simple example (in which $Y$ and $Z$ also are independent), that is, $X, Y, Z$ are *pairwise* independent but not mutually independent, and so $X$ is not independent of the bivariate random variable $(Y,Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Think of $Y=Z$. Then $X,Y$ and $X,Z$ are independent but...

Comment: ... $X$ is independent of $(Y,Z)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: haha.